# Shift via a condition

Tags: bash

I need to shift positional arguments and wonder whether the following command is valid?

```
shift $((sft==2))
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it do what you want? Assiming you know what the parts involved are, is there some reason to doubt it wouldn't work?

Comment: It works but is it safe to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's valid in any POSIX shell as long as

- you don't forget to quote that expansion as otherwise it's subject to split+glob and would return an error if `$IFS` contained `0` or `1`:

  ```
  shift "$(( sft == 2 ))"
  ```

  (the spaces inside are not required, I'm just adding them for legibility; in the general case though, spacing can make a difference like in `bash -c 'echo "$((a-$1))"' bash -1` which returns a `bash: a--1: syntax error in expression (error token is "1")` so it's a good habit to use spacing in arithmetic expressions).
- `$sft` contains an integer literal (in decimal without leading 0s or hexadecimal; numbers with leading 0s are meant to be treated as octal, though some shells ignore that requirement. In the case of bash, not only they are treated as octal but that's even if there are 8 or 9 digits in them in which case it returns an error).
- beware that if `$sft` is 2 and the number of positional parameters is 0, you'll get an error, `shift "$(( $# && sft == 2 ))"` would avoid that.

`$(( sft == 2 ))` expands to either 0 or 1, and [POSIX `shift`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_26) does accept 0 as argument in which case it does nothing.

Other ways to write it could be:

```
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ "$sft" -eq 2 ]; then
  shift
fi
```

(also POSIX and safer if `$sft` is not guaranteed to contain a number, using `[[...]]`, `$((...))` or `((...))` would introduce a command injection vulnerability in that case in bash; `[`'s arithmetic comparison operators also treat numbers with leading 0s as decimal).

In Korn-like shells including `bash`:

```
if (( $# && sft == 2 )); then
  shift
fi
```

Or:

```
(( $# && sft == 2 )) && shift
```

(though beware that the overall exit status will be non-zero if the conditions are not met, `(( $# == 0 || sft != 2 )) || shift` wouldn't have the problem).

In zsh:

```
shift "$# && sft == 2"
```

(the argument is interpreted as an arithmetic expression there).

Or using a short form of `if`:

```
if (( $# && sft == 2 )) shift
```